# makefile not changing input filename

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to make a C program and have the following makefile:

```
CC=clang
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall -pedantic
LDFLAGS=
LDLIBS=
OUT=nes_slop
SRC_DIR=src/
OBJ_DIR=obj/
SRCS=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)*.c)
OBJS=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR),$(notdir $(SRCS:.c=.o)))
MAKE=make
CLEAR=TRUE

all: clean $(OUT)

clean:
    rm -i $(OUT) $(OBJS) -f

$(OUT): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(OUT)

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $< -o $@
```

It was all well and good until I had more than 1 .c file:

```
clang -c -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -lncurses  src/gamestate.c -o obj/gamestate.o
clang -c -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -lncurses  src/gamestate.c -o obj/main.o
```

so, somehow the source file is not being updated, it's always `gamestate.c`... what's wrong with my makefile? any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: You should use a `.c.o:` suffix rule, rather than a rule that lists all the sources and objects.

Comment: `$(OBJS): $(SRCS)` tells `make` that *all* members of `$(OBJS)` depend on *all* members of `$(SRCS)` but your command refers to the builtin variable `$<` so only uses the first file from the dependency list.  There's almost certainly a dupe for this somewhere.

Comment: You want to use [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html) for your `$(OBJS)`  (you can get away with regular pattern rules as well...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, your rule should look something like this:

```
$(OBJS): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $< -o $@
```

You may also want to read [this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) for how to generate automatic dependencies (so if you change a header file, your c files will automatically regenerate as needed)   There's a TL;DR section at the top of that page, if you're not interested in the details.